# Golf yourself a beer

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, random

It's friday! Which means it's time for beer!
Sadly though, today we will be golfing beer instead of drinking it. :(

#### Challenge

Output a beer and drink it. The amount of sips you take changes your output.

#### Sips

Your program should take one input string. This string can solely consist out of concatenated `sip`s.
If the input is an empty string, you should output a full beer glass, including foam.

The more sips you take, the emptier your beer glass will be.

If you take 0 sips, your beer still has foam. The output of this foam is always the same (see examples).

If you take 1 sip, you should output the beer glass, followed by a new line and the string `Yuck, foam.`.

If you take 1 or more sips, your beerglass should not contain anymore foam, but should show the top of your glass. Drinking the foam counts as one sip.

If you take 6 or more sips, you should output an empty beer glass, followed by a new line and the string `Burp`.

For each sip you take, your beer glass should become emptier. How full your beerglass is depends on the amount of bubbles `°` (`&#176;`) in your beer. For each sip you take after the foam, a line of bubbles should be removed. Each line of beer can contain a minimum of `1` and a maximum of `5` bubbles. The position of these bubbles should be 100% random.

#### Examples

**input**

`empty input string, or no input at all`

**output**

```
  oo  o oo 
 oooooooooooo
o|  °     ° |\
 |     °    | \
 | °°    °  |} |
 |  °    °  | /
 |     °   °|/
 \__________/
```

**input**

`sip sip sip`

**output**

```
 ____________
 |          |\
 |          | \
 |     °    |} |
 |° °     ° | /
 | °    °   |/
 \__________/
```

**input**

`sip sip sip sip sip sip sip sip sip sip`

**output**

```
 ____________
 |          |\
 |          | \
 |          |} |
 |          | /
 |          |/
 \__________/
Burp
```

[This pastebin](http://pastebin.com/AsdYR60G) contains a list of inputs and outputs. Remember that the bubbles in the beerglass should be random!

#### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest code in bytes wins!

Happy <s>drinking</s> golfing!

Comment: You might want to note that `°` is the character with code point 176.

Comment: 176 in Latin-1 and Unicode, to be more specific.

Comment: Is a trailing newline on inputs except 1 and 6+ acceptable?

Comment: @ETHproductions yes. Will edit in when on laptop

Comment: By 100% random does that mean that running the same input over and over should produce different acceptable mugs, and that the distribution of bubbles should be even for each bubble spot?

Comment: The mug outputs should remain the same. The amount of bubbles on each line should differ every run. There can be only one bubble on each line, or up to 5. That's the random part of the challenge

Comment: Is the foam fixed or also random?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/Japt), 189 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859)

I almost went insane while trying to get this to work properly...

```
U?S+'_pC +R:"  oo  o oo\n "+'opC +"\no")+"\\, \\,} |, /,/"q', £(V=(!Y«U?"|: |" +SpA +'|+X,(1+5*Mr)o mZ=>Ul <Y*4+4©(V=Vh2+A*Mr ,'° ),V)qR +"\n \\"+'_pA +'/+R+(Ul ¥3?"Yuck, foam.":Ug22 ?`B¨p:
```

#### [Try it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=9b914b60365b0031f09d30c79d98d504131f1328&code=VT9TKydfcEMgK1I6IiAgb28gIG8gb29cbiAiKydvcEMgKyJcbm8iKSsiXFwsIFxcLH0gfCwgLywvInEnLCCjKFY9KCFZq1U/Inw6IHwiICtTcEEgKyd8K1gsKDErNSpNcilvIG1aPT5VbCA8WSo0KzSpKFY9VmgyK0EqTXIgLCewICksVilxUiArIlxuIFxcIisnX3BBICsnLytSKyhVbCClMz8iWXVjaywgZm9hbS4iOlVnMjIgP2BCqHA6&input=InNpcCBzaXAgc2lwIg==)

<sub>(Note: This program was made for an older version of Japt, and doesn't currently work in the latest version. To get around this, the older version is specified in the URL. Unfortunately, this also means the top-right code box doesn't work.)</sub>

This is *by far* the longest program I have ever written in Japt. Here's a breakdown:

**Step 1:** Create the top of the beer mug.

```
U?S+'_pC +R:"  oo  o oo\n "+'opC +"\no")

           // Implicit: U = input string
           // Begin the ASCII art with:
U?S+       //  If U is not an empty string, a space +
'_pC +R:   //   "_".repeat(12) + a newline.
:"..."+    //  Otherwise, this string +
'opC +     //   "o".repeat(12) +
"\no")     //   a newline and an "o".
```

If U is an empty string, this makes:

```
  oo  o oo
 oooooooooooo
o
```

Otherwise, this makes:

```
 ____________
```

**Step 2:** Create the middle rows of the mug.

```
+"\\, \\,} |, /,/"q', £(V=(!Y«U?"|: |" +SpA +'|+X,

+"..."    // Add to the previous string: this string,
q', £(    // split at commas, with each item X and its index Y mapped to:
V=(       //  Set variable V to the result of concatenating:
!Y«U?     //   If Y is 0 and U is an empty string,
"|: |"    //    "|"; otherwise, " |";
+SpA      //   10 spaces,
'|+X,     //   "|", and X.
```

This results in the previous string plus:

```
 |          |\
 |          | \
 |          |} |
 |          | /
 |          |/
```

**Step 3:** Add the bubbles.

```
(1+5*Mr)o mZ=>Ul <Y*4+4©(V=Vh2+A*Mr ,'° ),V)

            // Note: We're still looping through the five rows at this point.
(1+5*Mr)    // Generate a random integer between 1 and 5.
o           // Create an array of this many integers, starting at 0.
mZ=>        // Map each item Z in this range to:
Ul <Y*4+4©  //  If the length of U is less than Y*4+4,
            //  (in other words, if there's less than Y+1 "sip"s)
(V=Vh   '°  //   Insert "°" at position
2+A*Mr      //    2 + random number between 0 and 9.
),V)qR      // Finally, return V, and join the five rows with newlines.
```

At this point, the mug looks something like this:

```
 ____________
 |          |\
 |          | \
 |     °    |} |
 |° °     ° | /
 | °    °   |/
```

**Step 4:** Add the final row and optional text.

```
+"\n \\"+'_pA +'/+R+(Ul ¥3?"Yuck, foam.":Ug22 ?`B¨p:

+"\n \\"    // Add a newline and " \".
+'_pA       // Add 10 "_"s.
+'/+R       // Add a slash and a newline.
+(Ul ¥3?    // If the length of U is 3 (i.e. 1 "sip"),
"..."       //  add the string "Yuck, foam.".
:Ug22 ?     // Otherwise, if U has a character at position 22 (six or more "sip"s),
`B¨p        //  decompress this string ("Burp") and add it.
:           // Otherwise, add nothing.
```

Now everything is ready to be sent to output, which is done automatically. If you have any questions, feel free to ask!

Comment: It's been 3 days. RIP brain

Comment: @Bas I had it mostly written yesterday, but it wasn't my brain so much as my browser that died ;) I'll get it written today.

Comment: I'm glad your brain is still functioning, and I'm looking forward to see an explanation of this <s>monstrosity</s> beautiful piece of code

Comment: @Bas Explanation is ready :-)

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>283</s> 281 bytes

```js
s=>` `+(u=`_________`,(s=s&&s.split` `.length)?u+`___
 `:` oo  o oo
 oooooooooooo
o`)+(i=0,l=q=>`|`+[...u].map(_=>Math.random()>.8&i>=s&&b++<5?`°`:` `,b=0,i++).join``+(b|i<s?` `:`°`)+`|`+q+`
 `)`\\`+l` \\`+l`} |`+l` /`+l`/`+`\\`+u+`_/
`+(s&&s<2?`Yuck, foam.`:s>5?`Burp`:``)
```

### Explanation

```js
s=>
  ` `+(u=`_________`,        // u = 9 underscores
  (s=s&&s.split` `.length)   // s = number of sips
    ?u+`_
 `:` oo  o oo
 oooooooooooo
o`)                          // print glass top or foam

  // Print glass lines
  +(i=0,                     // i = line number
    l=q=>                    // l = print glass line
      `|`+[...u].map(_=>     // iterate 9 times
        Math.random()>.8     // should we put a bubble here?
        &i>=s                // has this line already been sipped?
        &&b++<5              // have we already placed 5 bubbles?
          ?`°`:` `,          // if not, place the bubble!
        b=0,                 // reset the number of placed bubbles
        i++                  // increment the line counter
      ).join``               // put the 9 spaces and bubbles together
      +(b|i<s?` `:`°`)       // place a bubble at 10 if none were placed
      +`|`+q+`
 `                           // print the suffix of this glass line
  )`\\`
  +l` \\`
  +l`} |`
  +l` /`
  +l`/`

  +`\\`+u+`_/
`                            // print the bottom of the glass
  +(s&&s<2?`Yuck, foam.`
    :s>5?`Burp`:``)          // print the message
```

### Test

```html
Input: <input type="text" id="sips" /><button onclick="result.innerHTML=(

s=>` `+(u=`_________`,(s=s&&s.split` `.length)?u+`___
 `:` oo  o oo
 oooooooooooo
o`)+(i=0,l=q=>`|`+[...u].map(_=>Math.random()>.8&i>=s&&b++<5?`°`:` `,b=0,i++).join``+(b|i<s?` `:`°`)+`|`+q+`
 `)`\\`+l` \\`+l`} |`+l` /`+l`/`+`\\`+u+`_/
`+(s&&s<2?`Yuck, foam.`:s>5?`Burp`:``)

)(sips.value)">Go</button><pre id="result"></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, <s>277</s> <s>265</s> 263 bytes

Assuming 1-byte-linebreak. Add one to `14` and `17` on Windows.

```
$r=str_pad(($i=$argc-1)?"":"  oo  o oo",16).str_pad("
 ",14,_o[!$i])."   ".($s="
 |          |")."\\  $s \\ $s} |$s / $s/
 \__________/
 ".($i<6?$i-1?"":"Yuck, foam.":burp)if(!$i){$r[34]=o;$i=1;}for(;$i++<6;)for($n=rand(1,5);$n--;)$r[17*$i+rand(2,11)]="°";echo$r;
```

Run with `-r`. line breaks may need escaping.

**breakdown**

```
// draw beer glass
$r=
    // first line: empty or foam
    str_pad(($i=$argc-1)?"":"  oo  o oo",16)
    // second line: top or foam
    .str_pad("\n ",14,_o[!$i])
    // other lines: empty glass+bottom
    ."   ".($s="\n |          |")."\\  $s \\ $s} |$s / $s/\n \__________/\n"
    // lyrics
    .($i<6?$i-1?"":"Yuck, foam.":burp)
;

// add foam left to the glass
if(!$i){$r[34]=o;$i=1;}

// add bubbles
for(;$i++<6;)
    for($n=rand(1,5);$n--;)
        $r[17*$i+rand(2,11)]="°";

// output
echo$r;
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for failing to answer your question in time but the foam should be fixed. However, if it improves your byte count I guess it may be random too. My bad for not clearly specifying, so use it to your advantage

Comment: @BassdropCumberwubwubwub Actually random foam costs. I just saw that everyone had it fixed while I was coding and kept mine random for a start.